# calling a function from another script

Tags: r

I want to use a function from one script in another script but i either get an erorr or nothing is happend, depend on my code syntax. When i use the `source("file_name)` i get an erorr, and when i add the `if(exists("function_name", mode = "function"))` i get nothing..

hope you can help
have a good day
Or

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? what's your working directory? Is the same folder where the file is in? Use getwd() to identify it. If it's different you have to insert the complete path in source().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a different way you can choose your code script file using file.choose (avoiding problems related to the working directory) like this:

```
source(file.choose())
```

Comment: This is bad practice. As such, the script cannot be run independently.

Answer (score 1):

Terru_theTerror is absolutely right: it looks like there is something wrong with your source folder.

You may check the current name of your working directory with `getwd()` and check what contains this directory by `dir()`. If there your source file is placed elsewhere, your should change your current directory or to include the path to your source file by using `source()`:

```
source_dir_name <- "D:/Work/Sources"
source_file_name <- "file_Name.R"
source_with_path <- paste(source_dir_name,"/", source_file_name, sep = "")
# 
setwd(source_dir_name)
source(source_file_name)
# or
source(source_with_path)
```